# How to add class on each item using while loop

Tags: php, html, foreach, while-loop, advanced-custom-fields

I just want to add a class on each items using the while loop in php. But the problem is it will add only to the item that is greater than 2, not to all items. My goal is to add class "nav-multiple" on all items if the items is exceed to 2.

```
<ul>
    <?php
    $index = -1;

    // loop through the rows of data
    while ( have_rows('property_section_menu_repeater_field') ) : the_row();
        $index++;
        $title = get_sub_field('property_section_menu_repeater_subfield1');
        $unique_id = get_sub_field('property_section_menu_repeater_subfield2');
    ?>
        <li class="nav-item <?php echo $index >= 2 ? 'nav-multiple' : ''; ?>">
            <a class="nav-link p-0" href="#<?php echo $unique_id; ?>"><?php echo $title; ?></a>
        </li>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
</ul>
```

Current output:

```
<li class="nav-item">
    <a></a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item nav-multiple">
    <a></a>
</li>
```

The output that i want to achieve:

```
<li class="nav-item nav-multiple">
    <a></a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item nav-multiple">
    <a></a>
</li>
```

Comment: You are comparing to the current index. What you need is to compare with total number of results.

Comment: It seems you're using the ACF library. Try and check their docs to see if there's a function that returns the number of rows.

Comment: Thank you @El_Vanja. I used php count() function and switching from while to foreach to make it easier and its working now.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I solved it now by using php count() function and foreach loop

```
<ul>
    <?php
    $rows = get_field('property_section_menu_repeater_field');
    // loop through the rows of data
    foreach($rows as $key => $row):
        $title = $row['property_section_menu_repeater_subfield1'];
        $unique_id = $row['property_section_menu_repeater_subfield2'];
    ?>
    
        <li class="nav-item <?php echo count($rows) >= 2 ? 'nav-item-multiple' : ''; ?>">
            <a class="nav-link p-0" href="#<?php echo $unique_id; ?>"><?php echo $title; ?></a>
        </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```